# Android: Button is faded gray when it should be transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I want a basic button that has a completely transparent background (so the only thing visible is the text.)

As per other answers, I've set `android:background="#0000"`, but still, it has a faded gray color.

Here is the complete layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3176C0">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:text="TRANSPARENT?" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What it looks like:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it is not a background showing, but a shadow from the default button style.

Therefore, the answer is that the button style needs to be changed by adding this to the button:

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ...

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is borderlessbutton.
Refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#Borderless

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```